# MySQL replication fails with error

Tags: mysql, replication, master-slave

I've got two mysql servers and they are configured to act as master and slave for mysql replication. Things works fine till I execute following query against the master database. The query runs without any issues on master and the replication fails with the given error.

I tried executing the same query against the slave directly and then it runs fine. What would be the issue and how I can solve the things up?

The error message (Query is also there)

```
Error 'Table 'micro.PROFILE' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'micro'. Query: 'INSERT INTO profile_copy (SELECT *,99,NOW() FROM PROFILE WHERE p_id=155)'
```

Comment: You need to post the relevant schema, and you're off topic.

Comment: Its not off topic. The given error is what I got when I ran "show slave status" on slave..

Comment: It's off topic because it isn't about programming, and not providing the schema when asked to do so makes it eligible for closure for other reasons. Try dba.stackexcchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to continue replication, you can use these commands on slave server:

```
SET GLOBAL SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER=1; START SLAVE;
```

Slave server skip the insert query and continue replication.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. I did the same but when it has replicate the same query after a while it gets failed again. Isn't there any other permanent fix for this?

Comment: Did you check exist the 'micro.PROFILE' on the slave? May be table has errors and slave server marks it unsusable.